# Meta chat doesn't work over https

Tags: bug, chat, ssl

It's great to be able to load chat over https, however while chat.stackexchange.com and chat.stackoverflow.com work, chat.meta.stackexchange.com doesn't:

> Attackers might be trying to steal your information from **chat.meta.stackexchange.com**
>
> You attempted to reach **chat.meta.stackexchange.com**, but instead you actually reached a server identifying itself as **chat.stackexchange.com**. This may be cause by a misconfiguration on the server or by something more serious.

Is this a misconfiguration, or is something more serious afoot?

Comment: The answer is the same as for all HTTPS issues -- currently, HTTPS is available on an "if you happen to try it it may work" basis and not officially supported. I'll defer it our DDoS team (Distributed Department of Sysadmin) whether this certificate problem is easily fixed, but I can say that you needn't worry about "something more serious".